# Upgrade from SDL Triion 2011 SP1 to Web8

Tags: 2011, web8, upgrade

The Installation zip file we used is SDL Web 8.1.1 release

I was successfully able to upgrade the Tridion Content Manager from Tridion 2011 SP1 to web 8.1.0.0 refer table TDS_DB_INFO

After upgrading when you  click on a page and say publish we still see the publising target  see below screen shot example : staging / LIVE .

I have not setup topology and business process yet. Is this a expected behavior or let me know if i am missing anything  let us know  how do we remove the mapping since we don't see the publication management any more.

Please Clarify.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed expected behavior.

To get rid of the old targets you will first need to un-hide the Publication Management node which can be done as per the instructions here:

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3F49BCA1-4201-477E-928E-53E2E2143322

And to delete the old Publishing Targets, you would need to decommission them first and then delete them (you can't delete them if something is already to them). To decomission the Publishing Targets you can use the following PowerShell command:

```
Clear-TcmPublicationTarget -PublicationTargetIds tcm:0-x-65537
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the update Kunal. Let say I un-hide the publication management and Clear the Publication Target  before I setup the business types and topology. How do we know which item is published to staging only and which item publish to staging and LIVE. In that case we might end up publishing all items.

Comment: I would prefer to generate my own report with Core Service API to get a list of which content has been published to staging and which one to live. Also please mark the post as answer if it solves your problem.